# How to set TransactionManager on job-repo and step tasklet when Multi Datasource was used

Tags: spring, spring-batch, multiple-databases

I has a Spring Batch App like that.

Reading data from DB(product) and Saving to DB(newLagacy).

```
<bean id="transactionManager_dataSource_newLagacy"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource_newLagacy" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager_dataSource_product"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource_product" />
</bean>


<bean id="jobRepositor_product" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager_dataSource_product" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource_product" />
</bean>

<job id="job" job-repository="jobRepositor_product" incrementer="incrementer"xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager_dataSource_newLagacy">
            <chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="mysqlItemWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

And 2 Datasouces.

```
    <bean id="dataSource_product" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" primary="true">

       ......

    <bean id="dataSource_newLagacy" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
       ......
```

'dataSource_product' is also used for Save Spring Batch Meta Tables( batch_* tables ).

'dataSource_newLagacy' is used for Load Data From a DB.

This setting is OK.

But, When I change tasklet transaction-manager to

"transactionManager_dataSource_product",
the problem occured.

In Detail, After Writing items, When Writing a Batch history.

```
2018:02:27 18:01:50.809 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.b.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter : Writing to flat file with 1000 items. 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.817 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.b.c.s.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet : Inputs not busy, ended: false 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.818 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep : Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=1000, written=1000, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING] 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.818 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.818 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.819 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate : Executing prepared SQL update 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.819 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?] 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.845 INFO  --- [main] o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana] 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.845 DEBUG --- [main] o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory : Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@37095ded] 
2018:02:27 18:01:50.847 WARN  --- [main] o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory : Error while extracting database name - falling back to empty error codes 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:342)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:212)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:233)
```

I want to know the reason why Exactly.

One thing make me confuse is that

the same transaction manger between job-repo and step tasklet tx-manager makes truble(connection close)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the reason.

The DB, i called 'product', was set that the variable 'wait_timeout' to '60' sec. 
When The query time over 60 sec, the connection was closed and need to Be reconnect. But the transaction means No other connection. 
So, When I set no transaction, It will be OK( Even if connection was closed, It will be reconnect). 
But the other, It has to be fail. Because It is in a transaction.